# Вывод строк из таблицы в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос, где рандомно выводится строка из 1-ой таблицы, при этом она содержит особый идентификатор, по нему нужно проверить если ли во 2-ой таблице запись с этим идентификатором. Если есть запись то снова делается рандомный запрос и происходит такая же проверка. Но дело в том что все это уходит в вечный цикл, и как бы это проверку нужно ограничить.
Вот наброски:

```
$res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}tasks` WHERE user NOT IN ($user_id) AND status=1 AND ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ;", ARRAY_A);
    foreach($res as $key) $idZad = $key['id'];
```

Выведет строку с уникальным id.
Нужно проверить есть ли в другой таблице

```
$pr = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT progress FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}completed`  WHERE id_user=$user_id AND id_task=$idZad", ARRAY_A);
foreach($pr as $progress) $progress = $progress['progress'];

if ($progress!=1) 
{
    //выполняем скрипт дальше.
}
else
{
    //нужно следующую запись проверить
}
```

Итак все это в цикл, только если таблицы дублированы нужно выйти из цикла. И сказать что все нечего проверять все уже проверил

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}tasks` WHERE user NOT IN ($user_id) AND status=1 AND ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 ;", ARRAY_A); // select id from, а не select * from зачем тбе лишние поля???
    foreach($res as $key) $idZad = $key['id']; // зачем здесь foreach? если ты тащишь всего одо значение?
Выведет строку с уникальным id. Нужно проверить есть ли в другой таблице

$pr = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT progress FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}completed`  WHERE id_user=$user_id AND id_task=$idZad", ARRAY_A);
foreach($pr as $progress) $progress = $progress['progress'];
// зацикливается наверно тут?
$progress потом опять ты ему присваиваешь значение его же, что за бред-то?

Тут условие срабатывает? хоть как нибудь? первое или после else?
if ($progress!=1) 
{
    //выполняем скрипт дальше.
}
else
{
    //нужно следующую запись проверить
}// ну проверил ты запись, и где дальше код который проверяет далее идти или не идти?
```

Что-то тут с логикой хмуро и пасмурно, я вот ничего не понимаю. Слишком много кода для такой простой вещи.

Comment: ЧТобы проще было по другому опишу.
1 таблица: id_task, name
2 таблица: id_user, id_task, progress.

Comment: Из 1 таблицы вывожу рандомно строку (теперь знаю id_task и заранее известен id_user к примеру=1) и смотрю какой progress во второй таблице у строки, где id_task получил из 1 таблицы, id_user=1. Если progress=1 то снова нужно выбрать рандомную запись из первой и проверить какой progress у нее во второй таблице, как только наткнусь на progress=0 продолжаю работу дальше, но одно "но" возможно так что во второй таблице у всех progress будет 1 и при проверке циклом все это в вечный цикл уйде

Comment: Так может быть тогда проще будет выбрать из второй таблицы случайную запись, у которой progress=0?

Если таких записей нет - значит у всех progress=1. Иначе - по id_task можно получить и name задачи, если это требуется.